# What is the best way to version the yaml files?

Tags: yaml, openapi, azure-api-management

I'm working on a API project on a hybrid cloud. APIs are hosted on-premise and via the cloud service (Azure API Management service), the APIs are exposed to the external world. For any APIs, we are writing the contract in Open API Specification as Yaml file manually and then import it into Azure APIM. Everytime yaml is imported in APIM, the version number in the Yaml get's reset to 1.0, even though it is something different in the Yaml file (unless we modify it manually after the import). This is creating confusion on what version is in the cloud vs what version is there locally. So, I'm looking for option if anybody faced this issue and how did they resolve it? One of the workaround solution that we have been doing is writing the version number in description when revising the version in Azure APIM.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [new version of an existing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started-publish-versions) and then import your updated OpenAPI spec using the update method as below

[image: import-api-to-version]

[image: import-method-update]

Also, something that you might already be doing is to maintain your OpenAPI specs in a `git` repository for version control since its like any file.

Comment: This appears to only support importing JSON. How can we import a spec in YAML?